# How to convert server datatime to clients datetime ? C#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a issue that the when clients saves their data it saves the data in server date..Due to this they are unable to fetch their data according to date and time..Server Time is in Usa and clients time is in India ? Your ideas will be welcome

Comment: You should work with datetime offset values, then you have the time and the offset which allows you to convert the time to any other timezone (offset).

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved? If the answer helpful accept it by clicking on the checkbox to help others.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert USA date to Indian date. I have read this tutorial and says how you can do that and more! Please check it. [MSFT Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get `Indian Local Time`

```
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

                DateTime utcTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();

                TimeZoneInfo indZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

                DateTime yourLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, indZone);
```

> For further customization you could follow below `Interface` on screen
>   shot. Just explore it by pressing `F12` on `FindSystemTimeZoneById` on
>   above mentioned code.

[image]

If you want to know more details about different time conversion please refer to this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=netframework-4.8) additionally [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones#converting-datetimeoffset-values)